# Installing wordpress in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to amazon-web-services and unaware of most of the things in it. I have setup an wordpress site on Linux EC2 instance with EFS storage.
I have also used Amazon RDS as a database service for my wordpress site with below description
    
Engine : MySQL
        
DB engine version : MySQL 5.6.40
        
DB instance class : db.t2.micro
        
Allocated storage : 60GB

Earlier i was able to browse my wordpress site through  domain  but later when I accidentally stop EC2 instance, due to autoscaling policy it was replace with new EC2 instance. Now I was unable to browse wordpress site. What would I do now to get my site running, all what I tried seems to worthless.

Comment: `all what I tried seems to worthless` - what/how did you try? How did you access your web site? Through IP address? Domain name mapped to the IP address? After a restart, public IP address may change unless you have an attached a static "Elastic IP Address"

Comment: In testing phase I used IP address  to browse the site after that  i mapped it to my domain using Route 53. I missed to mention about the testing phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the instance has stopped accidentally, your autoscaling group will invoke a new instance with a new IP address unless you have an attached Elastic IP.

As you mentioned accessed your website through IP address/DNS name of your instance, it will be recorded in the **'Home URL' and 'Site URL'** fields in the wp_options table of your WordPress database.
Hence, when you use the new IP address/DNS name/Domain, it will get redirected to the old IP address.

So, in this case, you need to modify 'Home URL' and 'Site URL' fields in the **wp_options** table of your WordPress database.

**Please follow the below steps:**

-SSH to your instance and login to your database.

-To check the existing values for 'Home URL' and 'Site URL' fields :

```
select * from wp_options where option_name like “home%”;

select * from wp_options where option_name like “site%”;
```

-To update those values:

```
update wp_options set option_value = “New IP/Domain to be updated” where option_name =”siteurl”;

update wp_options set option_value = “New IP/Domain to be updated” where option_name =”homeurl”;
```

Comment: thank you so much @Aress support,after making changes in wp_options table i was able to resolve my issue.